# no resource identifier found for 'ptrMode' in package

Tags: android

I need help getting rid of this error, i wonder if any of you guys have encountered this problem while using pulltorefresh. i have imported the lib for both viewpager and listfragment and still getting no resource identifier error.

```
  <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ptrlvAddFollowingResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/actvAddFollowingSearch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#19000000"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        ptr:ptrMode="pullFromEnd" 
   />
```

Comment: Why you don t use the offical pulltorefresh (SwipeRefreshLayout)?

Comment: i am trying to use that now, in this case i am modifying someone else's project. thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the declare-styleable "PullToRefresh" at attrs.xml of the ViewPagerIndicator library in the attrs.xml of your own project.
In my case, thats solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use this library with resources, did you add the following line in  `project.properties`?

```
 android.library.reference.1=path/pull-to-refresh
```

if you already have `android.library.reference.1` you need to use `android.library.reference.n` where 
`.n index in the references must begin at "1" and increase uniformly without "holes"` (from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)).